# How do I set the the security group of a service to the default security group when using CDK

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group

I am writing an app that uses an Opensearch domain and a Lambda and has them both inside a private subnet of a VPC. When I was testing on the console, I found that I would get a timeout error anytime I tried to access the domain from the lambda. I was able to resolve this by manually setting the security group on both the domain and lambda to the default security group. I tried to do this in the cdk by using: `securityGroups : ec2.SecurityGroup.fromLookupById(this,'def_sec_group',serviceVPC.vpcDefaultSecurityGroup)`, but I get an error:

```
All arguments to look up a security group must be concrete (no Tokens)
```

From what I can gather, this is because the CDK doesn't get the actual VPC yet, it just creates a token until it is deployed. I tried instead to modify other security groups and use those. The CDK makes default security groups for both the lambda and the opensearch domain and so I was going to just try to modify those to fit the default security group for the VPC. The only difference I could tell was the the VPC has an inbound rule: with source set to itself and no descriptors for the ip type. I realized I probably wouldn't be able to access those default security groups anyway since they would be tokens, so I was going to try to make new security groups. That still leaves me with the issues for what to input as the peer and connection for the SecurityGroup cdk constructor.

Answer (score 0):

When setting up Security Group access you'll want to look at using the Connections class on the resources.

```js
const domain = new Domain(...);
const lambda = new Function(...);
domain.connections.allowDefaultPortFrom(lambda);
```